# How does one solve ODE with some domain constraints?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, mathematical-modeling

So far I have no clue, how to go about this .. in school we did not go over constraint based ODES.

So let's say we have

$\ x'' = -ax' $

$\ y'' = -ay' - b $

Note: a,b are constant and x(t), y(t).

$\ x(0) = X_{i} $

$\ y(0) = Y_{i} $

$\ x'(t_{end}) = V_{xf} $

$\ y'(t_{end}) = V_{yf} $

How do I solve for a solution in which I want some constraint such that let's say 
when

$\ 10<x<11 $ then $ y > 10 $

in words (when x is between 10 and 11, y has to be more than 10).

Is there any numerical way to solve this type of situations ? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can solve the equation analytically.  Do you want it to work in a more general setting?  The way you phrased the question makes it look like you want a yes-or-no answer, but it also sounds like you're choosing between a variety of solutions - which solutions?

Comment: ohh any as long as (when x is between 10 to 11, y has to be above 10)

Comment: So are you saying you don't care what the initial conditions are?  For given initial conditions there is only one solution, which may or may not have y>10 whenever 10<x<11.  And again, your example is relatively trivial because you can find an exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the two ODEs are not coupled. Let's focus on
$$
x^{\prime\prime}\left(t\right)=-ax^{\prime}\left(t\right)\text{ for }0<t<t_{end}.
$$
The general solution is
$$
x\left(t\right)=c_{1}e^{-at}+c_{2}\text{ for }0<t<t_{end}.
$$
where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are arbitrary. We need to satisfy the initial conditions. On the left-hand boundary,
$$
x\left(0\right)=X_{i}=c_{1}+c_{2}
$$
so that $c_{2}=X_{i}-c_{1}$. On the right-hand boundary,
$$
x^{\prime}\left(t_{end}\right)=V_{xf}=-ac_{1}e^{-at_{end}}
$$
so that
$$
c_{1}=-\frac{V_{xf}e^{at_{end}}}{a}.
$$
You can use the same ideas to solve the other one.